# Is it possible to backup shell folders in XP with VB or WSH script?

Tags: windows-xp, backup, vbscript, wsh

I would like to backup shell folders on my XP machine. It is useful for me because when I reinstall XP I can just restore those backed up shell folders.

Can you guys get me started or point me in the right direction?

```
'*************************************
' Author:
'
' This script backs up shell folders.
'
' Source:
' Destination:
'
'-------------------------------------
'Rev #          Changes
'-------------------------------------
'1.0            started
'*************************************

'*********
'VARIABLES
'*********

dim filesys
dim source
dim destination

source="C:\Documents and Settings"
destination="C:\Temp"    'will change in future revisions

'*********
'OBJECTS
'*********
set filesys=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


if filesys.FolderExists(source) Then
    filesys.MoveFolder source, destination
    MsgBox("Folder Moved")
End if
```

Comment: You can use any type of scripting you'd like. Where exactly do you want to back up the folders to? secondary HD, network share, ftp site?

Comment: to a partition. I want something to get started with. I have started the script in my edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of a simple batch script to copy your My Documents folder to a folder on another drive/partition

> @echo off
>
> if not exist "S:\backup" mkdir "S:\backup"
>
> xcopy "%userprofile%\My Documents" "S:\backup" /e /v /c /h /r /y

Comment: will it also backup shell files on a network drive if i just specify "F:\backup" etc. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You may have better luck using the SpecialFolders ([Described Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ea7b5xe%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) than hard coding your path to the source folder since the OS will manage locating the actual folders, which might not be at C:\Documents and Settings or any such location.